# Removing particular string with special character and number

Tags: php, regex

I have following example its working fine but i want to remove Issue No1 – ,Issue No2 – ,Issue No3..... at once because I don't want to add Issue No2 – , Issue No3 ... everytime in preg_replace. I think this is possible with preg_replace. I wrote following code but did not get the actual result. Any advise or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

```
$catName="Issue No1 – This is new Issue No2 – This is also new item Issue No3 – This is new one There are 1 2 3 items ....... ";
echo $catName= preg_replace("/Issue No\d+/","",$catName);
```

Output should be:

This is new This is also new item This is new one There are 1 2 3 items .......

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: Please see updated code

Comment: Looks like all you are missing are the spaces and minus sign at the end. What output do you have now exactly?

Comment: sorry see updated code. I want to remove Issue No1 – Issue No2 –  and so on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also have to add `-` at end of your expression

```
preg_replace("/Issue No\d+ –/", "", $catName);
```

[DEMO](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/lu7#preg-replace)

Comment: It is more simple and direct regex than BeingExpert answer.

Comment: Yes i was confused in \d+. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try like below -

```
$catName = preg_replace("(Issue No[0-9]+)", "", $catName);
```

Comment: How would the output of your code be different from what the OP has?

Comment: @jeroen : Ohh, It seems the question is edited . Thank you for the notice.

Comment: @PawanKumar : I think earlier there was question which is deleted and now you have asked new kind of similar again , am I correct? My bad I thought its same as earlier. sorry

Comment: Sorry for updating my answer Question was same. Thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $catName="Issue No1 - This is new Issue No2 - This is also new item Issue No3 - This is new one There are 1 2 3 items ....... ";
    echo "<h1>$catName</h1>\n";

    $catName = preg_replace("/Issue No\d+ - /","",$catName);
    echo "<h1>$catName</h1>\n";

?>
```